How to extract file extension from filepath field in PostgreSQL?
need to extract file extensions from the file_path column from my PostgreSQL table. kindly help me to achieve to extract the distinct file extensions as list using select query.
have table like this



id
file_path




1
https://example.com/uploads/profile_pic.jpeg


2
https://example.com/public/upload/resume.png



expected output like is



row_no
extension




1
jpeg


2
png



my query
select reverse(substring(reverse(file_path) from 1 for strpos(reverse(file_path),'.')-1)) as extension from pgsql_table_files;


So what exactly is the question you have?

need to get a select query to get list of extensions @phaen

Using SPLIT_PART(): SELECT SPLIT_PART('https://example.com/public/upload/resume.png','.', -1) or REGEXP_REPLACE(): SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('https://example.com/public/upload/resume.png','^.*\.(.*)$', '\1')

Check if this works for you SELECT id AS row_no DISTINCT substring(file_path from '\.([^.]*)$') AS extension FROM pgsql_table_files;

SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "DISTINCT"
Position: 35

A simple solution using split_part from here String Functions.
create table file_ext(id integer, file_path varchar);
insert into file_ext values (1, 'https://example.com/uploads/profile_pic.jpeg'), 
(2, 'https://example.com/public/upload/resume.png'), 
(3, 'https://example.com/public/upload/cover_letter.png'), 
(4, 'https://example.com/uploads/cat_pic.jpeg');

select * from file_ext ;
 id |                     file_path                      
----+----------------------------------------------------
  1 | https://example.com/uploads/profile_pic.jpeg
  2 | https://example.com/public/upload/resume.png
  3 | https://example.com/public/upload/cover_letter.png
  4 | https://example.com/uploads/cat_pic.jpeg


select distinct split_part(file_path , '.', -1) as extension from file_ext;
 extension
------------
 png
 jpeg


Use split_part to break the string on . and then use reverse indexing(-1) to fetch the last split which is the extension. Then use DISTINCT to fetch only one record for each extension.
If you want to include a row number then:
select 
   distinct on(split_part(file_path , '.', -1)) row_number() over() as row_no, 
   split_part(file_path , '.', -1) as extension from file_ext;

 row_no | extension 
--------+------------
      1 | jpeg
      2 | png



great! thanks.. very short and sweet
